# How can I center align in pandas dataframe only cell that i want

Tags: python, pandas

```
writer=pd.ExcelWriter('Data.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')
emptydf.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=('Sheet1'),na_rep='-')
concat5.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=('Sheet2'),na_rep='-')
workbook=writer.book
writer.save()
```

[image]

What I want is align to center only cells that "-". It is aligned to left right now.
I want to know how i could this. 
Thank you.

Comment: Originally, All "-" cells are expressed "NaN". I changed to "-".

Comment: Have a look here - [Horizontal text alignment in openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671581/horizontal-text-alignment-in-openpyxl)

Comment: I want to align only cells that contain "-".

Answer (score 0):

This is an `openpyxl` solution:

```
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('Data.xlsx')
ws_names=wb.get_sheet_names()

for ws_name in ws_names:
    for row_cells in wb.get_sheet_by_name(ws_name):
        for cell in row_cells:
            if cell.value == '-':
                cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

wb.save('Data.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got all i want.